# Is there a way to extend the duration of Blade Ward or higher-level spells similar to it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

Is there  a way to extend the duration of [*blade ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blade-ward) or higher-level spells similar to it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to extend the duration of a cantrip instead of just casting it again? This will help inform answers since methods of extending that take more than an action would not solve the issue if the casting action is the issue.

Comment: What class the caster is?

Answer (score 8):

## Blade Ward, No.  Stoneskin, Yes.

Stoneskin is nearly identical to Blade Ward, except it is a level 4 spell, requires concentration, lasts an hour, and is specific to **non**-magical physical damage (Blade Ward works against any non-spell attack). Stone Skin can also be cast on allies.

If you needed to extend it out longer than 1 hour, you can use Metamagic from being a Sorceror (gets both Stoneskin *and* Blade Ward) to double the duration to 2 hours.  This effect cannot be duplicated with Blade Ward, unfortunately, due to the duration requirement for the Metamagic that says the spell must have a duration of 1 minute or more.

Comment: To clear up any confusion, Blade Ward prevents Bludgeoning, Piercing, or Slashing damage from weapons.  Stoneskin prevents non-magical Bludgeoning, Piercing, or Slashing damage.  This means that neither of these spells can prevent damage from spells, but Blade Ward works against magical weapons, and Stoneskin can block damage from traps, and both work against non-magical weapons.

Comment: Based on a prior question, I found out that Traps are considered weapon attacks if they are resisted with AC, but are not weapons if you are required to make a save.

Comment: You should update your answer accordingly. *Blade ward* does indeed apply to all weapon attacks, whether that's from weapons, unarmed strikes, or traps. In other words, it applies to anything that makes an attack roll that's not a "spell attack".